# HTML - how to call displaying such this?

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm confused and have no idea how to make displaying child's like this http://prntscr.com/5huiw9 . I have code with result : http://prntscr.com/5hukpa

```
article.item{
width: 220px;
height: auto;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px/8px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px/8px;
border-radius: 10px/8px;
background-color: #fff;
border: solid 1px #d5d5d5;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 30px;
padding: 0 40px;
text-align: center;

}
article.item:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

and as you can see, the result is not the same as should be. So what is the best choise to make grid like mentioned below?

Comment: Yet another [**Masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Kushagra Agarwal have a nice example on how to make this only with css, here is the link to deck with example http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout but you can use plugins like http://masonry.desandro.com/ or http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ to get the wanted result

Comment: thanks for link, I tried to use isotopo and I still have a problem. http://prntscr.com/5hv6rp, code: http://jsfiddle.net/ctn29eu3/1/ where is the problem? there should be 3 childs in a row, but fits only 2

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jErVMR

Comment: thanks, but not as should be. http://prntscr.com/5hvuz3 there is empty space on the right. All childs should be 220px width

Comment: oh, I made it by changing .item_article width to 32% and in js `columnWidth: $container.find('.item_article')[0],
            gutter: 15` but still have a problem with sorting. I need to sort all items in row, but it mixes items... for ex. you can see item 5 have to be in 6 item place.. http://prntscr.com/5hw6ro

Answer (score 0):

Zurb's Foundation and Masonry.js mentioned earlier will make your "masonry styled" grid a snap to create. This link from Zurb has four easy steps to get you going: http://zurb.com/university/lessons/65